How to display a notification on an Android 14 device while using background location service - Flutter
I need to fetch location in background.
I'm using following packages:

geolocator: ^13.0.1
location: ^7.0.1

When I'm testing with an Android 10 device, the app is working perfectly.
But when I'm testing with an Android 14 device, notification will not be displayed an when I minimize or lock the screen fetching background location is paused.
Can anyone help me with this?
Here's my code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart' as loc;

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  Future<void> _determinePosition() async {
    final location = loc.Location();
    bool serviceEnabled;
    loc.PermissionStatus permissionGranted;

    serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!serviceEnabled) {
        print('GPS service is not enabled');
        return;
      }
    }

    permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (permissionGranted == loc.PermissionStatus.denied) {
      permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (permissionGranted != loc.PermissionStatus.granted) {
        print('Location permission is denied');
        return;
      }
    }

    location.enableBackgroundMode();

    final locationSettings = AndroidSettings(
      accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
      distanceFilter: 100,
      forceLocationManager: true,
      intervalDuration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    );

    Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings)
        .listen((Position? position) {
      print(position == null
          ? 'Unknown'
          : '${DateTime.now()} | ${position.latitude.toString()}, ${position.longitude.toString()}');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Test')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print('Start');
            _determinePosition();
          },
          child: const Text('Start'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
        android:label="test"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>


